# Prompt for 5 words then display longest word javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, split, prompt

I am trying to prompt for a 5 words then separate the words to find the longest word then display the longest word using java script. I am able to get anything to work, it wont even prompt for the words.

```
function longestWord(string) {
    var word = prompt("Enter a string of at least 5 words separated by spaces:") ;
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    str.forEach(function(str) {
        if (longest < str.length) {
            longest = str.length;
            word = str;
        }
    });
    return word;
    document.write("The longest word is " +word+ ".") ;
}
longestWord(string)
```

Comment: `document.write("The longest word is " +word+ ".") ;` is unreachabe as it is after return statement

Comment: You did `string.split(" ")` it should be `word.split(" ")`

Comment: You also don't need to pass anything to the longestWord function.

Comment: Summing up comments above: http://jsfiddle.net/fcsey7s1/

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple words that are the longest? http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/u589dgey/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling longestWord with string as a parameter, which is undefined.

```
<script>
function longestWord() {
    string = prompt("Enter a string of at least 5 words separated by spaces:") ;
    var str = string.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    str.forEach(function(str) {
        if (longest < str.length) {
            longest = str.length;
            word = str;
        }
    });
    document.write("The longest word is " +word+ ".") ;
}
longestWord();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working version of your function, combining all the comments on the original question.

```js
function longestWord() {
    var word = prompt("Enter a string of at least 5 words separated by spaces:") ;
    var str = word.split(" ");
    var longest = 0;
    str.forEach(function(str) {
        if (longest < str.length) {
            longest = str.length;
            word = str;
        }
    });
    return word;
}

document.write("The longest word is " + longestWord() + ".");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it differently: separate

```js
function longestWord(string) {
  var str = string.split(" ");
  var word = str[0];
  for (s of string.split(" ")) {
    if (s.length > word.length) {
      word = s;
    }
  }

  return word;
}
var words = prompt("Enter a string of at least 5 words separated by spaces:");
lw = longestWord(words);
document.getElementById("longest_word").innerHTML = "The longest word is " + lw + ".";
```

```html
<div id='longest_word'>
  longest word:
</div>
```

the function from the activity: